# Substitute unmatched left angle brackets in HTML

Tags: bash, awk, sed

My problem: How to find lines with unmatched left angle brackets and replace these brackets with their HTML equivalents.

Example input:

```
<dd>
     Pro 10g Flüssigkeit: 2g Wasserstoffperoxid <10% Tenside. ENTHÄLT: Sulfamidsäure,</dd>
```

Expected output by substituting the unmatched '<10%' string:

```
<dd>
     Pro 10g Flüssigkeit: 2g Wasserstoffperoxid &lt;10% Tenside. ENTHÄLT: Sulfamidsäure,</dd>
```

There are German 'Umlaute' included in my example text just in case they could 'mess something up'...

I would like to use sed or awk if possible.

I have read:
[Use sed with regex and (](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548446/use-sed-with-regex-and), [How to decrement (substract) number in file with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812531/how-to-decrement-substract-number-in-file-with-sed/25812532#25812532) and
[sed - regex square brackets detection in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684551/sed-regex-square-brackets-detection-in-linux) and other Q&A but I can't seem to get my head around regexes. Sorry!

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be good enough:

```
$ sed -E 's/<([^>]+<)/\&lt;\1/g' file
<dd>
     Pro 10g Flüssigkeit: 2g Wasserstoffperoxid &lt;10% Tenside. ENTHÄLT: Sulfamidsäure,</dd>
```

If not then edit your question provide a more complete (but still concise and testable) example that truly represents your real input.

There's nothing special about an umlaute or any other input character btw.

Comment: Regarding umlaute: I was parsing vCards (i.e. plain ASCII files) when a completely normal looking 'ü' in a surname terminated my awk script. 
I have never found out why thousands of these vCards (many containing Umlaute and 'ß' and all from the same source) got parsed without any problem but this one did not work. Therefore ...

Comment: If any character terminated (or had any other adverse effects on) your awk script then you plain and simple have a bug in your awk script. That simply does not happen otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dangerous proposal, because `sed` works on a line-by-line basis, and for each line, there are several cases to consider:

There could be only the less-than character without any html tags:

```
<p>
    x < 10
</p>
```

There could be, as in your example, a html tag after the less-than character

```
<p> x < 10 </p>
```

The less-than character could be inside a html tag.

```
<img src="..." alt="Graph for x < 10">
```

It could be a really long html tag which is closed in a later line.

```
<img
    src="..."
    alt="..."
>
```

What I'd do is to at first assume only the first two options are present, then use something like this:

```
sed -i.orig -r 's/<([^>]*($|<))/\&lt;\1/g' file.
```

This will keep a backup of the original file with the new extension `.orig`, so that you can then run a `diff` program over both to see what has changed.

As for how this works:

- `s/AAA/BBB/g` replaces any occurrence of `AAA` with `BBB`
- `s/A(CC)/B\1/g` replaces `ACC` with `BCC`, that is the part in the parenthesis is inserted for the `\1`
- `[^>]*` means zero or more of any characters **other than** `>`
- `($|<)` is either the end of line or `<`, whichever comes first.

So it searches for a `<` without a `>` until either the next `<` or the end of the line, and replaces that part with `&lt;` and everything that it found after the initial `<`